# xquery beginner- how to select nth node within a div containing text as well as 'p' tags enclosing some more text

Tags: xquery

Given below is some HTML code corresponding to a div in a web page--

```
<div id="1">
    Text #1
    <p> Text #2 </p>
    Text #3
</div>
```

What I am confused about is, do I treat "Text #1" as the first child node, and "Text #3" as the 3rd child node, within the div with id=1? Because "Text #1" and "Text #2" are not enclosed within any HTML construct, while "Text #2" is enclosed within a "p" construct.

What will be the Xquery expression that retrieves the text "Text #3" from the expression above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apply the `descendant::text()` step to retrieve all text nodes and choose the third node:

```
(<div id="1">
    Text #1
    <p> Text #2 </p>
    Text #3
</div>//text())[3]
```

Comment: when you use descendant::text(), will that also select the content within p (i.e. "Text #2") as the second node?  Thanks....

Comment: yes - just try ;) if you use BaseX, you may switch on the "Realtime Execution" mode to get immediate query results.